# python ray pid unavailable in RayTaskError

Tags: python, ray

I am running a function as number of ray tasks, collecting the object ids in a list called `futures`.

I then have a try/except block within which I attempt to get the results.  My function throws a `RuntimeError`.  My understanding is that ray wraps this within a `RayTaskError`.  I want to catch the `RayTaskError` and print its pid.

```
...
try:
   results = ray.get(futures)
except ray.exceptions.RayTaskError as e:
   print(e.pid)
```

Doing this gives me `AttributeError: 'RuntimeError' object has no attribute 'pid'`

If I change `print(e.pid)` to simply `print(e)` then I do see a lot of information including the pid:

```
ray::file_process_worker() (pid=22996, ip=127.0.0.1)
  File "python\ray\_raylet.pyx", line 850, in ray._raylet.execute_task
  File "python\ray\_raylet.pyx", line 902, in ray._raylet.execute_task
  File "python\ray\_raylet.pyx", line 857, in ray._raylet.execute_task
  File "python\ray\_raylet.pyx", line 861, in ray._raylet.execute_task
  File "C:\Defacto offline\PriceTransparency\pt_ray_spike\ptrans\fileprocessors\basefileprocessor.py", line 601, in file_process_worker
    raise RuntimeError(err_msg)
RuntimeError: Error processing file sample.txt
```

If I print the type of the exception with `print(type(e))` then I get

```
<class 'ray.exceptions.RayTaskError(RuntimeError)'>
```

Looking at [the source code](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/_modules/ray/exceptions.html#RayTaskError) it seems like the pid should be available as an attribute.

So my question is, ***why am I unable to get the pid from the exception?***

---

**2023.03.27 update**

Adding a breakpoint within the exception handling block and inspecting what's available, I see that `e` is an object of `<class 'ray.exceptions.RayTaskError(RuntimeError)'>` and has the attributes:

- `cause`: a `RuntimeError` object (which was thrown by the remote function being executed)
- `args`: a tuple containing a single member, the `RuntimeError` object.
- `_annotated`: a string 'RayTaskError'

Comment: Can you try entering a debugger in the exception handler and exploring what attributes are available?

Comment: @cade thanks for the suggestion, I've updated the original question with information from the debugger.  As a workaround I am adding the pid of the remote process to the RuntimeError thrown by the remote function, and then logging the `cause` attribute in my exception handler.  But I still don't understand why there is no `RayTaskError.pid` available.

Comment: Nice fix! I don't know why it isn't there -- why don't you create a github issue against ray-project/ray and request that the pid be available in the RayTaskError?

Comment: Ok so I'm not missing anything obvious?  I've only been using ray for a week and thought I probably wasn't understanding something.

Comment: I don't think you're missing anything!